# Linq2Sql Submit changes does nothing on update

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq2Sql and trying to update a table.

But no update happens when I try to update a column.

I have tried it with the attach statement but then I get a duplicate key error.

I am using my own entity and copying it over to the context entity as you can see.

Is that my problem?

This is my save method.

```
   public void SaveUser(User user)
    {

        Mylester.Domain.DataContext.User sqluser = new Mylester.Domain.DataContext.User();

        sqluser.usrID = user.ID;
        sqluser.usrEmployeeID = user.EmployeeID;
        sqluser.usrFirstName = user.FirstName;
        sqluser.usrLastName = user.LastName;
        sqluser.usrPassword = user.Password;
        sqluser.usrEmail = user.Email;
        sqluser.usrModified = user.Modified;
        sqluser.usrCreated = user.Created;
        sqluser.usrLastLoggedOn = user.LastLoggedOn;
        sqluser.usrBrowserUsed = user.BrowserUsed;
        sqluser.usrLoginOnly = user.LoginOnly;
        sqluser.usrViewedWeeklyTimesheetChanges = user.ViewedWeeklyTimesheetChanges;
        sqluser.usrActive = user.Active;

        //_dbctx.Users.Attach(sqluser);
        _dbctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

This is my test method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void UpdateUser()
{
    User user;

    user = _service.GetUser(1474);
    user.FirstName = "TestXXXX";
    _service.SaveUser(user);

    user = _service.GetUser(1474);
    Assert.AreEqual(user.FirstName, "TestXXXX");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using my own entity and copying it over to the context entity as you can see.
>
> Is that my problem?

Yes, this wrecks the `DataContext`s [identity map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map) (used for entity tracking). The easiest way to update is approximately:

```
User user = _dbctx.Users.Single(u => u.usrID == 1474);
user.FirstName = "TestXXXX";
_dbctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

Before Submitting changes, you should add statement `"dbcontext.tablename.InserOnSubmit(object);"` 
method.

```
public void SaveUser(User user)
    {

        Mylester.Domain.DataContext.User sqluser = new Mylester.Domain.DataContext.User();

        sqluser.usrID = user.ID;
        sqluser.usrEmployeeID = user.EmployeeID;
        sqluser.usrFirstName = user.FirstName;
        sqluser.usrLastName = user.LastName;
        sqluser.usrPassword = user.Password;
        sqluser.usrEmail = user.Email;
        sqluser.usrModified = user.Modified;
        sqluser.usrCreated = user.Created;
        sqluser.usrLastLoggedOn = user.LastLoggedOn;
        sqluser.usrBrowserUsed = user.BrowserUsed;
        sqluser.usrLoginOnly = user.LoginOnly;
        sqluser.usrViewedWeeklyTimesheetChanges = user.ViewedWeeklyTimesheetChanges;
        sqluser.usrActive = user.Active;
        //Use this to add the sql user to table named "User"
         _dbctx.Users.InsertOnSubmit(sqluser);
        //_dbctx.Users.Attach(sqluser);
        _dbctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
```